# How do I build and install mpv?

Tags: dpkg, compiling, 20.10, mpv-media-player

The reason why I want to build it myself? That is because the one off the store does not work with youtube links. I also want what is the latest of MPV player.

What I want to know is how would I build and install the MPV player? The first answer on Google gave me an error message. I am running on Ubuntu 20.10. The error message reads as this:

```
dpkg-buildpackage: error: cannot open file debian/changelog: No such file or directory
```

So, what do I do, considering I am still new to linux?

Comment: So what did you do to to get this error message? Edit your question and list every step from downloading to executing commands. This way no one knows what you've done

Comment: @kanehekili I said I did what the first google result said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building an mpv package is possible but a little difficult as the [supplied instructions](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv-build) need some modification to work under Groovy Gorilla.  The more sensible thing to do is to simply *repair* the existing Ubuntu Repository package of mpv under Groovy Gorilla. This is quite a reasonable package but its YouTube playback suffers because it ships an *older* version of youtube-dl.

First install mpv from the Ubuntu Repository as usual:

```
sudo apt-get install mpv
```

After this remove the older version of youtube-dl (2020.09.14) that has come with this installation; and then install *the very latest* youtube-dl:

```
sudo apt-get remove youtube-dl
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo apt-get install python-is-python3
```

Now test your mpv installation against a great YouTube clip:

```
mpv --autofit=800 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZbZSe6N_BXs'
```

And I suspect that you, like myself, will be listening to Pharrell William's 'Happy' message successfully playing with mpv :).

[image]